# How to get the extent of a PostGIS raster table?

Tags: postgis, postgis-raster

For vector data, it is possible to get the extent of an entire table using either [ST_Extent](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Extent.html) or [ST_EstimatedExtent](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_EstimatedExtent.html).

How does one get the total extent of all rasters in a raster table?

Comment: Can you use [ST_Summary](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Summary.html)?

Answer (score 2):

You can look up the extent of a raster layer by looking at the `extent` column of the `public.raster_columns` table.

Comment: Thanks. I checked `public.raster_columns`, but the `extent` column for the specific raster table I have is empty or NULL.

Comment: how did you add the raster? As far as I know that field should be set on creation or modification